# Doing some calculations in mysql, numbers off when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

Im running the following query to get the stats for a user, based on which I pay them.

```
SELECT hit_paylevel, sum(hit_uniques) as day_unique_hits
       , (sum(hit_uniques)/1000)*hit_paylevel as day_earnings
       , hit_date 
FROM daily_hits 
WHERE hit_user = 'xxx' AND hit_date >= '2011-05-01' AND hit_date < '2011-06-01' 
GROUP BY hit_user
```

The table in question looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `daily_hits` (
  `hit_itemid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hit_mainid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hit_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hit_date` date NOT NULL,
  `hit_hits` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hit_uniques` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hit_embed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hit_paylevel` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`hit_itemid`,`hit_date`),
  KEY `hit_user` (`hit_user`),
  KEY `hit_mainid` (`hit_mainid`,`hit_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The problem in the calculation has to do with the hit_paylevel which acts as a multiplier. Default is one, the other option is 2 or 3, which essentially doubles or triples the earnings for that day.

If I loop through the days, the daily `day_earnings` is correct, its just that when I group them, it calculates everything as paylevel 1. This happens if the user was paylevel 1 in the beginning, and was later upgraded to a higher level. if user is pay level 2 from the start, it also calculates everything correctly.

Comment: This is a good example of why I dislike the way MySQL handles `GROUP BY`. The `hit_paylevel` varies by row within your group and MySQL arbitrarily chooses one to use.

Comment: @Joe: actually, this is really a MySQL issue. PostgreSQL would reject the query altogether, complaining that it doesn't know which hit_paylevel to pick...

Comment: @Denis: Yes, that was my point. I dislike that MySQL considers this a legal query.

Comment: @Joe, I love the way MySQL handles group by, You just need to be very aware of it so you don't get bitten. It has its uses though.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be `sum(hit_uniques * hit_paylevel) / 1000`?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Denis said:

Change the query to

```
SELECT hit_paylevel, sum(hit_uniques) as day_unique_hits
       , sum(hit_uniques * hit_paylevel) / 1000 as day_earnings
       , hit_date 
FROM daily_hits 
WHERE hit_user = 'xxx' AND hit_date >= '2011-05-01' AND hit_date < '2011-06-01' 
GROUP BY hit_user;
```

**Why this fixes the problem**
Doing the `hit_paylevel` **outside** the sum, first sums all `hit_uniques` and then picks a random `hit_paylevel` to multiply it by.
Not what you want. If you do both columns inside the sum MySQL will pair up the correct `hit_uniques` and `hit_paylevels`.

**The dangers of group by**
This is an important thing to remember on MySQL.
The `group by` clause works different from other databases.
On MSSQL *(or Oracle or PostgreSQL) you would have gotten an error

> non-aggregate expression must appear in group by clause

*Or words to that effect.*

In your original query `hit_paylevel` is not in an aggregate (sum) and it's also not in the `group by` clause, so MySQL just picks a value at random.

Comment: Tried this. The sum looks to be a lot closer to the value it should be, but its still a little bit off from the number I should have if I manually add the numbers by looping thru the results.

Comment: @Yegor, if either `hit_uniques` or `hit_paylevel` can be null then the expression `hit_uniques * hit_paylevel` evaluates to 0 (because the sum doesn't count them).

Comment: neither of them do. They will be at least equal to 1